# How to restart App Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

The iPhone app has an option to "restart" a service plan. Can anybody tell me where this is located in the portal? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we now have a way to do that (without requiring a direct API call as suggested by @krzysztof-madej in his [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1129331/380056)). The current location seems a bit strange to me, but you can choose any app currently running within the plan, then navigate to **Monitoring** > **Health Check** > **Instances**. Then you can click Restart to restart the specific instance of your plan.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this only via [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/reboot-worker)

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{name}/workers/{workerName}/reboot?api-version=2022-03-01
```

This will restart the single machine. So if you have two instances you need to run it for each instance separately.

I recommend trying the option `Try it` from the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

In the Azure portal go to your App Service Plan. In the left menu click `Apps` under `settings`. Then click on your app to open the app's settings. There you will have an option to restart the App

Comment: I am not looking for a way to restart an app. I am looking for a way to restart the whole "service plan". (The mobile app has this function, one can archive the same thing [or something similar] if you change the pricing tier.)

Comment: I see, unfortunatly this feature is not available in the portal. Such a feature was [requested in 2017](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/17826847-restart-app-service-plan-all-web-apps-in-a-plan#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20restart,each%20iteration%20of%20the%20loop.) and declined by the Azure App Service team.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the feedback site. i posted a comment there. Do you happen to know what the "restart service plan" button in the mobild app does?

Comment: Not 100% sure what the mobile app does exactly, but I suspect it call the `Restart Web App` function [documented in the REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/restartwebapps)